# How to reset Bootstrap Form

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here im using Bootstrap validations with AngularJs when my form is submitted the columns is reset but its shows all validation..But my aim is its should not display validations

**Bootstrap**

```
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <form name="f1" novalidate ng-submit="Save(Auth.emp)">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        Email
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="Auth.Email" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                                        <span class="Error" ng-show="(f1.email.$dirty ||Submitted) && f1.email.$error.required">Email REq</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        Password
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" name="psw" class="form-control" ng-model="Auth.Password" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                                        <span class="Error" ng-show="(f1.psw.$dirty ||Submitted) && f1.psw.$error.required">Password REq</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" value="{{LoginAction}}" />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**AngularCode.Js**

```
$scope.Save = function (emp) {
        if ($scope.LoginAction = "Login") {
            $scope.Submitted = true;
            if ($scope.isFormValid == true) {
                var ss = {
                    Email: $scope.Auth.Email,
                    Password: $scope.Auth.Password,
                }
                var xxer = myServices.GetLogin(ss);
                xxer.then(function (msg) {
                    $scope.msg = msg.data;
                    $('#modal2').modal('show')
                     Reset();
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

**Reset**

```
function Reset() {
        $scope.Email = '';
        $scope.Password = '';

    }
```

Comment: Reset the f1 var: $scope.f1 = {email:null, psw:null};

Comment: no use its showing error at var :

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this:

```
function Reset() {
     $scope.Auth.Email = ''
     $scope.Auth.Password = '';
}
```

Comment: exeactly  but when i used its just reset my columns not my validations i also used                      $scope.Auth.$setPristine(true);  but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can set a model at the same level as the form tag and make all other inputs sub properties. Then set form model at the root level to an empty object when you click on reset. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tlombrana22/pen/vyLOqd).

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.form = {};
  };
}
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" ng-app="app" ng-controller="exampleController">
  <form novalidate ng-model="form">
    <input ng-model="form.email" type="email" />
    <input ng-model="form.password" type="password" />
  </form>
  <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  <pre>{{form}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be the good idea to use . Also you can hide the reset button incase you dont want to show.